# Global settings for minted

Tags: minted

I'm working on a document where source code listings are largely in a single language, and where I would like to have a homogeneous listing style document-wide. Using an example from [the docs](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Code_Highlighting_with_minted), I would essentially like to make the following settings globally effective across my document:

```
\begin{minted}
[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
bgcolor=LightGray,
fontsize=\footnotesize,
linenos
]
% ... contents of code listing ...
```

Does the `minted` package offer a way to apply these options globally?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, there is the`\setminted` command for setting options for the whole document. From the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf):

> You may wish to set options for the document as a whole, or for an entire language. This is possible via `\setminted[<language>]{<key=value,...>}`. Language-specific options override document-wide options. Individual command and environment options override language-specific options.

Setting options only for inline commands can be done via `\setmintedinline`.